# What does the extends keyword mean in this context?

Tags: javascript

I am following a tutorial and it says myObject extends the toString object.

```
var myObject  = {};
console.log(myObject.toString());
```

Comment: It's nonsense. Extend doesn't mean anything in that context.

Comment: In JavaScript `Object.prototype.toString()` is defined already. You can override this method if you wish.

Comment: Check out: [MDN: `Object.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Comment: It might help if you quoted the tutorial

Comment: Its a video tutorial from tutsplus and you need to have a subscription to watch it

Comment: It sounds like a wrong tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean since there is no link/quote to the tutorial you mentioned but according to what I understand, you can extend/override Object.prototype.toString method in order to print in a format you wish. 
If not, it will use the default method, which will print  "[object type]"

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.toString = function(){ return "I'm my Object";}
console.log(myObject.toString()); //it will print "I'm my Object"
```

Ref: [toString() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)